# Angular filter on child property

Tags: angularjs

Hi I need to filter an angular list based on a child property.

I have this model:

```
  $scope.data = [{name:"John",type:{talent:"genius"}},
                 {name:"Paul",type:{talent:"genius"}},
                 {name:"Ringo",type:{talent:"lucky"}}];
```

I need to display a list of name of only talented people. So I was trying something like this:

```
item in data|myFilter:item.type
```

http://jsbin.com/ObIqUyix/1/edit

Comment: Hey, Ringo was a pretty good drummer!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is better because it'll let you have other properties in the type object as well and you can still filter using different properties:

```
item in data | filter: {type:{talent:'genius'}}:true
```

Comment: I would maybe even remove the first part, to avoid confusion, because it's the update that's answering the question.

Comment: Be careful not to set strict search by using `true` as the last argument if your nested object has other properties besides the one you are searching for. But otherwise, you could use the performance boost.

Comment: Perfect, worked with the ng-model also filter: {type:{talent: filters.talent}}