# AngularJS - Array as filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

How can I setup a filter in an `ng-repeat` that use strings and an array of strings?

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types| orderBy : 'name' | filter:{typology:currTipology}"
```

JavaScript

```
var myData = ['string_1', 'string_2', ['string_3', 'string_4']];
```

I'll use a button for every `myData` entry to assign the string value to ´currTipology`.

**UPDATE**
I try to better explain my issue.
I have a main object data with 6 different 'typology' properties.
I need to place 4 buttons: button 1 to 3 corresponds to 1 to 3 'typology' properties; the last button has to filter the 4 to 6 'typology' properties.
How should i use filters for last button?

Comment: What's the point of the filter?

Comment: I have to pick any value following 'string_1' and 'string_2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple filter you can do with function some thing like this

```
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:{name: companyName} | filter:gradeFilter">
```

And in controller you have your filter function some thing like

```
$scope.gradeFilter = function (employee) {
   if(employee.salary > 70000 && employee.exp > 3){ 
      return "Senior"
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter by following way

```
<div ng-repeat="subject in results.subjects | filter:{grade:'C'}">
   <input ng-model="subject.title" />
</div>
```

Comment: i know how to use a filter.
i need to know how to use a "mixed" filter

Answer (score 0):

See code snippet below for parsing sub-arrays (this will only work for 2 levels-deep arrays). Hope it does the job :)

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.myData = ['string_1', 'string_2', ['string_3', 'string_4']];
  
  $scope.isArray = function (type) {
    return typeof type === 'object';
  }
  
  $scope.isString = function (type) {
    return typeof type === 'string';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">  
  <div ng-repeat="type in myData">
    <div ng-if="isString(type)">
      {{type}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="isArray(type)" ng-repeat="subtype in type">
      {{subtype}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want a filter based solution, maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941297/angular-ng-repeat-filter-on-subarray