# AngularJS ng-repeat over an array with filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JS array of objects.

```
$scope.users = [{
    "name": "alice",
    "city": "london",
    "wards": [{
            "id": 1,
            "number": 24
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "number": 25
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "number": 26
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "bob",
    "city": "london",
    "wards": [{
            "id": 1,
            "number": 24
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "number": 25
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "number": 27
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I have a `ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchUser`

Here `searchUser` can contain *name*, *city* and *ward number*.
Now the search is working fine for *name* and *city* but not for the sub array of objects *wards* to search for *ward number*.

Is there an angularJS way with which I could achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941297/angular-ng-repeat-filter-on-subarray this might help

Comment: The answer over there only filters the items in the subarray not overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to write your own custom filter.

Here is a sample jsfiddle, tested with input search

alice, bob, london, 26, 27

http://jsfiddle.net/1dura7m3/

If you want exact match, then change -1 to 0

```
app.filter('myFilter', function(){
    return function(users, search){
    if(!search) return users;
    if(!users || !users.length) return users;
    searchInLower = search.toString().toLowerCase();
    users = users.filter(function(user){
        matches = false;
        if(user.name){
        usernameInLower = user.name.toString().toLowerCase();
        matches = matches || usernameInLower.indexOf(searchInLower) !== -1;
      }
      if(user.city){
        cityInLower = user.city.toString().toLowerCase();
        matches = matches || cityInLower.indexOf(searchInLower) !== -1;
      }
      if(user.wards && user.wards.length && !matches){
        for(var i = 0; i < user.wards.length; i++){
         ward = user.wards[i];
         for(var key in ward){
           objectKeyValueInLower = ward[key].toString().toLowerCase();
           matches = matches || objectKeyValueInLower.indexOf(searchInLower) !== -1;
         }
        }
      }

      return matches
    });
    return users;
  }
})
```